# Why is regex cutting my word?

Tags: python, nltk

My previous effort was something like this with Python NLTK

```
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer

a = "miris ribe na balkanu"

capt1 = RegexpTokenizer('[a-b-c]\w+')

capt1.tokenize(a)

['be', 'balkanu']
```

This is was not what I wanted,ribe was cut to be from b.This was suggested by Tanzeel but doesn't help

```
>>> capt1
RegexpTokenizer(pattern='\x08[abc]\\w+', gaps=False, discard_empty=True, flags=56)
>>> a
'miris ribe na balkanu'
>>> capt1.tokenize(a)
[]
>>> capt1 = RegexpTokenizer('\b[a-b-c]\w+')
>>> capt1.tokenize(a)
[]
```

How to change this,to stay just with last word?

Comment: @BoarGules Only last word 'balkanu'.

Comment: @MishaVacic I updated my answer since you updated your question. The new regex should work.

Comment: `\x08` is exactly wrong. It's a backspace character, which is what Python does to the string `"\b"` if you forget to make it a raw string. It should have been this: `r"\b"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you probably need is a word-boundary `\b` in your regex to match the start of a word.

Updating your regex to `\b[abc]\w+` should work.

**Update:**
Since the OP could not get the regex with the word-boundary to work with NLTK (the word-boundary `\b` is a valid regex meta-character) I downloaded and tested the regex with NLTK myself.

This updated regex works now `(?<=\s)[abc]\w+` and it returns the result `['balkanu']` as you'd expect.

Have not worked with NLTK before so I can't explain why the word-boundary didn't work.

Comment: NTLK's tokenizer already knows quite a lot about word boundaries, so your `\b` directed it to find tokens beginning with a word boundary, which of course cannot exist. That is why it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the RegexTokenizer is not to pull out selected words from your input, but to break it up into tokens according to your rules. To find all words that begin with `a`, `b` or `c`, use this:

```
import re
bwords = re.findall(r"\b[abc]\w*", 'miris ribe na balkanu')
```

I'm not too sure what you are after, so if your goal was actually to extract the last word in a string, use this:

```
word = re.findall(r"\b\w+$", 'miris ribe na balkanu')[0]
```

This matches the string of letters between a word boundary and the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing up the notions of matching and tokenizing.

This line

```
capt1 = RegexpTokenizer('[abc]\w+')
```

(don't do `[a-b-c]`) says that the tokenizer should look for `a`, `b` or `c` and count everything following, up to the end of the word, as a token.

I think what you want to do is tokenize your data, then discard any tokens that don't begin with `a` or `b` or `c`.

That is a separate step.

```
>>> capt1 = RegexpTokenizer('\w+')
>>> tokens = capt1.tokenize(a)
# --> ['miris', 'ribe', 'na', 'balkanu']
>>> selection = [t for t in tokens if t.startswith(('a','b','c'))]
# --> ['balkanu']
```

I've used `str.startswith()` here because it is simple, but you could always use a regular expression for that too. But not in the same one as the tokenizer is using.